# Progressbar re renders previous state when i reset the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a progresbar that receives a value as the width
When I click the "Reset" button it does reset the state to 0
and works as expected
However when I click the Reset button before the
progressbar is 100% width it will continue increasing the
state

How can i prevent this from happening?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function ProgressBar({ value = 0 }) {
  const [percent, setPercent] = useState(value);
  useEffect(() => {
    setPercent(value);
  }, [value]);
  return (
    <>
      {value.toFixed(2)}%
      <div
        style={{ display: "flex", width: "100%", border: "1px solid black" }}
      >
        <div
          style={{
            border: "1px solid black",
            backgroundColor: "red",
            height: "0.5rem",
            transition: 0,
            width: `${percent}%`
          }}
        ></div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [percent, setPercent] = useState(0);
  const [willReset, setWillReset] = useState(false);

  const step = 100 / 3;

  useEffect(() => {
    function updateProgress() {
      if (!willReset) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (percent + step > 100) {
            setPercent(percent + (100 - percent));
          } else {
            setPercent(percent + step);
          }
        }, 1000);
      } else {
        setPercent(0);
      }
    }
    updateProgress();
  }, [percent, willReset]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setWillReset(true);
        }}
      >
        Reset
      </button>
      {percent !== 100 && <ProgressBar value={percent} />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I put your code in sandbox without any modification and its works.
[Iink](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-bassi-5hs7x?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: you can  try and **disable the button** when the progress is not 100% this is how its done generally and professionally also for **example google forms**

Comment: Why not just set the percent to 100 instead of `percent + (100 - percent)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens is because you are using `setTimeout` inside of your `useEffect` hook. You must return a cleanup function from your `useEffect` callback to clear the `setTimeout` or else it will continue to be called.

I would write it like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (willReset) {
    setPercent(0);
    return;
  }

  const id = setTimeout(() => {
    if (percent + step > 100) {
      setPercent(percent + (100 - percent));
    } else {
      setPercent(percent + step);
    }
  }, 1000);

  return () => clearTimeout(id);
}, [percent, willReset]);
```

Comment: thank you very much, I was starting to feel frustrated